# How do I text myself in Google Hangouts in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I am using Google Hangouts via Gmail on a desktop web browser, and I want to send a text message to myself. Is it possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: You can email to your cell number and it comes in as a text. Check this reference guide for the proper format for your provider. http://www.emailtextmessages.com/ for instance, If my cell number was (123)456-7890 and I used AT&T as my provider I would email 1234567890@txt.att.net

Comment: No it is not possible to text yourself in hangout and you can follow "Ben Plont" suggestion as a work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Hangouts pane in Gmail, click on the phone icon (not the chat/text icon), then click the + icon near its top, then find yourself, then click SMS on yourself.

Answer (score 21):

You can achieve this by having a named group chat with no other members.

Start a new conversation, choose New Group, and enter a name for the group. After typing a name, you can start the group without having to add any people to it.

You'll need to send a message before leaving this screen, or the group will not get added to your conversation list. Once you've sent a message in the group, you can continue to use this group to message yourself in the future, or you can leave the group to terminate it.

Comment: Clever workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ben Plont and Vembu for their answers in the comments:

> No it is not possible to text yourself in hangouts.
>
> You can email to your cell number and it comes in as a text. Check this reference guide for the proper format for your provider. emailtextmessages.com for instance, If my cell number was (123)456-7890 and I used AT&T as my provider I would email 1234567890@txt.att.net

Answer (score 0):

Make a group then invite at least one person. After, kick them out[image: See, told you]